# How to make custom form in Wordpress who send the content and then create template post with this content? is this possible?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to create a textarea (form) who client can write his opinion about company, then this opinion is send to wordpress admin panel, or template post. Someone have any sugestion how to start?

Comment: I would advice to share some code you have tried into your question else it will be flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called front end publishing. There are a [number of plugins](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/best-frontend-publishing-wordpress-plugins) for that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned I would suggest having a look at the Ninja Form Plugin, lots of tutorials and documentation.
For the criteria that you mention I think Ninja Form would suite your needs.